# How to set default value for a function parameter of type TEncoding?

Tags: delphi, unicode, encoding, delphi-xe2

Converting from D2007 to XE2, I converted this function

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string) : boolean;
```

to

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string; Enc: TEncoding = nil) : boolean;
var
  AStr: ANSISTring;
begin
  Result := True;
  if Enc = nil then Enc := TEncoding.ANSI;
  try
//Old    FileStream.WriteBuffer( Pointer(ALine)^, Length(ALine) );
    if Enc = TEncoding.UTF8 then
      AStr := UTF8Encode(ALine)
    else
      AStr := ANSIString(ALine);
    FileStream.WriteBuffer( AStr[1], Length(ALine) );
    end;
  except
    Result := False;
  end;
end;
```

Rationale:

- Change code using Add_Line as little as possible
- Accept the automatic change to Unicode, only at the last moment write 8-bit text files (this is used in XML and CSV). In the future we could still move to UTF-16 files if we want.

I would have liked to define something like:

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string; Enc: TEncoding = TEncoding.ANSI) : boolean;
```

but the compiler complains ;-)

Is anything like that possible?

Comment: The restriction of default params to be constant values is one reason why I always favour using overloads.

Comment: Overloads never crossed my mind ;-)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Default arguments must be a compile-time constant, but if you need anything more advanced, you can create overloads:

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string) : boolean; overload;
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string; Enc: TEncoding) : boolean; overload;


function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string) : boolean;
begin
  Result := Add_Line(FileStream, ALine, TEncoding.ANSI);
end;
```

You can even add the `inline` keyword to get exactly the same generated code that the default argument would have resulted in, were it valid.

Note: you don't seem to support anything other than `TEncoding.ANSI` and `TEncoding.UTF8`. In that case, a `TEncoding` parameter seems overkill, you could use a `UTF8: Boolean` parameter instead (or rework your code to work with an arbitrary encoding's `CodePage`).

Note 2: `FileStream.WriteBuffer( AStr[1], Length(ALine) );` is wrong because `Length(ALine)` and `Length(AStr)` need not be the same, you should use `Length(AStr)` instead. Also, `AStr[1]` can result in an exception when `AStr` is an empty string, you can add a special case to only call `WriteBuffer` when `AStr` is not empty.

Comment: For future use I'll leave it a TEncoding parameter, and thanks for pointing out the Length() typo! Could lead to horrible data ;-)

Answer (score 6):

Others have commented on how you can specify a default value for the `TEncoding` paramter.  I want to point out that your use of `TEncoding` is completely wrong in general.

`TEncoding.UTF8` is not the only way you can obtain a UTF-8 encoding object (`TEncoding.GetEncoding(65001)` is another way), so checking for `TEncoding.UTF8` specifically is the wrong thing to do.  Worse, you are completely ignoring any non-UTF8 encodings and just encoding everuthing else to a plain `AnsiString`, which defeats the whole purpose of using `TEncoding` at all.  A user could pass in an ISO-8859-X encoding object, for instance, and your output would NOT be ISO encoded like the user requested.  You may as well change your parameter into a `UseUTF8: Boolean = False` parameter instead, because that is how you are effectively using it:

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string; UseUTF8: Boolean = False) : boolean;  
var  
  AStr: AnsiString;  
begin  
  Result := True;  
  try  
    if UseUTF8 then  
      AStr := UTF8Encode(ALine)  
    else  
      AStr := AnsiString(ALine);  
    if AStr <> '' then
      FileStream.WriteBuffer( AStr[1], Length(AStr) );  
  except  
    Result := False;  
  end;  
end;
```

The correct way to use `TEncoding` is to let it do the actual encoding, don't do the encoding yourself:

```
function Add_Line( FileStream : TFileStream; ALine : string; Enc: TEncoding = nil) : boolean; 
var 
  AStr: TBytes; 
begin 
  if ALine = '' then
  begin
    Result := True;
    Exit;
  end; 
  Result := False;
  try 
    if Enc = nil then Enc := TEncoding.Ansi; 
    AStr := Enc.GetBytes(ALine); 
    // GetBytes() returns 0 bytes if it fails to encode, it does not raise an exception!
    if Length(AStr) = 0 then Exit;
    FileStream.WriteBuffer( AStr[0], Length(AStr) )
  except 
    Exit;
  end; 
  Result := True;
end;
```